# How to replace polynomials numerically?

Tags: equation-solving, semantic-matching

We know that the value of this equation is 0

```
x2 y1 - x1 y2 == 0
```

For the following equation, there is a correlation between the polynomial parts of the known equation (opposite to each other).

```
-x1 y + x2 y + x y1 - x2 y1 - x y2 + x1 y2 == 0
```

Why can't the replacement be replaced with 0?

```
(-x1 + x2) y - x2 y1 + x (y1 - y2) + x1 y2 == 0 /. (x2 y1 - x1 y2) -> 
  0
```

Comment: Since you can read Chinese, check this also: https://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=77b86cb08aaf29ce8747990c9e717298

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Simplify[x1 y + x2 y + x y1 - x2 y1 - x y2 + x1 y2, 
 x2 y1 - x1 y2 == 0]
```

> `x1 y + x2 y + x (y1 - y2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it and replace it in the second, likeso:

```
sltn1 = Solve[x2 y1 - x1 y2 == 0][[1]];
DivideSides[
  Factor[(-x1 y + x2 y + x y1 - x2 y1 - x y2 + x1 y2 == 0) /. sltn1], 
  x1, Assumptions -> {x1 != 0}] // FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 1):

Side relation can be used (sometimes) but often they fail.

An alternative is to solve for one of the variables from the relation you want to use, and then replace that variable into the polynomial. This will always work. Like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
p    = (-x1+x2) y-x2 y1+x (y1-y2)+x1 y2==0
side = (x2 y1-x1 y2)==0
x2Sol= First@Solve[side,x2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
p/.x2Sol//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this method, which variable to solve for is arbitrary.